# Failed to install opencv-python through pip3 on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I searched this topic before but still I couldnt find the answer.
I'm trying a guide on Object Detection using tensorflow on Raspberry Pi. I'm currently using Raspberry Pi3. So I followed a guide and this is the place I got stuck, I stuck at installing opencv-python, no matter what I try it always comes out with

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python

The Raspbian Version I'm currently on is 
Raspbian Buster 10/7/2019
Python 2.7
Python 3.7.3

I'm not sure whether if it's the version of tensorflow/python is making me unable to install opencv-python. The current version of tensorflow on my RPi is 1.13.

I tried removing python 3.7 and installed python 3.5, but that led me to boot loop so I had to reinstall Raspbian again. 
I tried

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
pip3 install opencv-python
pip install opencv-python
```

None of them succeeded

Before installing opencv-python i need to install some dependencies, these codes run successfully ,

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev
sudo apt-get install libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools

pip3 install opencv-python (this is where I failed)
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python(fromversion:)

Comment: Tried `pip3 install python-opencv`?

Comment: @Jammy Dodger Is it the same?

Comment: @Jammy no i havent tried, is it the same?

Comment: I've heard it mentioned, and I believe it's the same

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install opencv-python
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to download the open-cv source code directly and use that instead: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python. You will have to compile and install the source yourself.

Comment: I'll try now and provide update. But I dont know how to install from source, from the link you provided... Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip
pip3 install opencv-python
```

I hope it works out.

Comment: Im not sure if it is because the Raspbian i installed is Raspbian Buster, and not Stretch which caused this failure. Nevertheless I installed thru source file...

Answer (score 0):

I could install OpenCV for buster on a 3B using apt:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
```

Depending on what you're doing you might need [these other packages](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=297834#p1793759):

```sh
sudo apt-get install libcblas-dev libhdf5-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libatlas-base-dev libjasper-dev libqtgui4 libqt4-test
```